# MATLAB error: Implementing formula and receiving / can't be used because matrix dimensions do not agree error

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph, plot, matlab-figure

I have a simple MATLAB program I wrote but I am getting errors. I am trying to plot `TS1`, `TS2` and `TS3` as a function of `t` from 0 to 40. However, I am getting various errors.

One of the errors I am getting is `"/ can't be used because matrix dimensions do not agree"` . I am also attaching a picture of the actual formula I am supposed to implement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
%Ground Surface Temperature Plot

clc;
clear;

var t
var e1
var e2
var e3
var Ts1
var Ts2
var Ts3


t = linspace(0,40,1000);
Ti = 285.93;
Twind1 = 244.2611111;
Twind2 = 238.7055556;
Twind3 = 233.15;
x = 0; 
h = 16.3987;
a = 13.78579*10^(-6);
k = 0.52;
L = 60.96;

e1 = erfc(x/(2*sqrt(a*t*86400)));
e2 = exp(h*x/k + h^2*a*t*86400/k^2);
e3 = erfc(x/(2*sqrt(a*t*86400))+(h*sqrt(a*t*86400)/k));

Ts1 = (e1 - e2*e3)*(Twind1 - Ti) + Ti;
Ts2 = (e1 - e2*e3)*(Twind2 - Ti) + Ti;
Ts3 = (e1 - e2*e3)*(Twind3 - Ti) + Ti;

figure
Plot(t,Ts1,t,Ts2,t,Ts3);
```

The formula that is being coded is below.

[image: Formula]

Comment: the formula could be seen in the imgur link below the code.

Comment: can you put the formula in LATEX in the question?

Comment: @AshaabAlam Can you verify that the error is resolved in my solution? It's quite possible you're not feeding in proper `x` values to generate your equation, but that should get you past the error if you need to do an element wise division.

Comment: Made some slight grammar corrections to improve flow of post.  Also changed title to better reflect question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs at this line.

```
e1 = erfc(x/(2*sqrt(a*t*86400)));
```

These are the sizes of the things you're trying to divide.

```
>> size(2*sqrt(a*t*86400))
ans =
           1        1000
>> size(x)
ans =
     1     1
```

I believe you are trying to do an element wise division so use `./` as follows.

```
e1 = erfc(x./(2*sqrt(a*t*86400)));
```

Note you need to do this whenever you are performing element wise division or multiplication between a number and matrices so edit `e2` and `e3` accordingly.